# Why can Into<String> accept String type?

Tags: rust

```
struct Person {
    name: String,
}

impl Person {
    fn new<S: Into<String>>(name: S) -> Person {
        Person { name: name.into() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let person = Person::new("test");
    let person = Person::new("test".to_string());
}
```

`&str` has `Into<String>` trait, so I understand that I can call `Person::new("test")` proprely.

However, I think that `Person::new("test".to_string())` fails because `String` does not have `From<String> for String`,  so `Into<String>` is not derived automatically.
Why can I call `Person::new("test".to_string())`?

In addtion, I can call the following code too.

```
let test: String = String::from("test".to_string());
```

In the above case, I cannot understand that I can call `String::from("test".to_string())` successfully even if `String` does not have `From<String> for String`.

Comment: [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) says: _`Into` is reflexive, which means that `Into<T>` for `T` is implemented_.

Comment: Sometimes you see this expressed as `fn new<S>(name: S) -> Person where S : Into<String>` to keep the declaration more compact.

Comment: Even better `fn new(name: impl Into<String>)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, I think that `Person::new("test".to_string())` fails because `String` does not have `From<String> for`String`, so` Into` is not derived automatically.

Actually, `From` (and thus `Into`) is reflexive:

```rust
// https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/convert/mod.rs.html#545-549

impl<T> From<T> for T {
    fn from(t: T) -> T {
        t
    }
}
```